# How can I use Cauchy-Riemann equations in this case to prove that $f$ is a null function?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> If $f = u + iv$ and holomorphic in $D$ such that all of its values are on the line $au+bv+c=0$, show that $f$ is a null function on $D$.

I was trying to use C-R equation to get to the result but the most that I get was the $-bu+av + k=0$ for some $k$ real, can I assume something by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean that, for each $x+iy\in D$ you have
$$
au(x,y)+bv(x,y)+c=0
$$
where one among $a$ and $b$ is non zero.

Since the above is an identity, you get
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)+
b\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)
=0
$$
and, similarly,
$$
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)+
b\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y)
=0
$$
By the Cauchy-Riemann equations, this can be rewritten as
$$
\begin{cases}
a\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)-
b\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)
=0
\\[4px]
a\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)+
b\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)
=0
\end{cases}
$$
Multiply the first by $a$ and the second by $b$, then sum, getting
$$
(a^2+b^2)\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=0
$$
and, similarly,
$$
(a^2+b^2)\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=0
$$
Therefore $u$ is constant on $D$. By Cauchy-Riemann again, also $v$ is constant.

The function need not be null, however.

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind give a hint about The manipulation in The case that f are in a circunference of radio r and center (a,b)?

Comment: @EduardoSilva Do you mean that $(u(x,y)-a)^2+(v(x,y)-b)^2=r^2$?

Comment: Exctaly! The manipulation is similar?

Comment: @EduardoSilva Yes, but a bit more delicate